# Return all NA's with row and column

Tags: r

I am trying to create some code that will loop through a data set and return the last completed row and column as a verctor.

The first column of the data set is the name of the student the rest of the data set represent sections of a program completed. The last column of each row that contains data represent the final section completed by the student.

Thus the output should be a vector of the following:

```
 name, sections that are blank and contain NA (i.e. 1_1 or 1_3 etc.) 
 name, sections that are blank and contain NA 
 name, sections that are blank and contain NA etc.
```

Here is the data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(list(names = c("John", "Peter", "Steve"),
                    '1_1' = c("yes", "yes","yes"),
                    '1_2' = c("yes", "yes", ""),
                    '1_3' = c("", "yes", "yes"),
                    '1_4' = c("", "","yes"),
                    '1_5' = c(NA, NA, NA)), 
               row.names = NULL)
df
#   names X1_1 X1_2 X1_3 X1_4 X1_5
# 1  John  yes  yes             NA
# 2 Peter  yes  yes  yes        NA
# 3 Steve  yes       yes  yes   NA

df<-apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("^|^", NA, x))
#   names  X1_1 X1_2 X1_3 X1_4 X1_5
# [1,] NA    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
# [2,] NA    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
# [3,] NA    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

I get the following after the gsub, which is meant to fill NA's into balnk spaces:

```
names   X1_1  X1_2  X1_3  X1_4  X1_5
[1,] "John"  "yes" "yes" NA    NA    NA  
[2,] "Peter" "yes" "yes" "yes" NA    NA  
[3,] "Steve" "yes" NA    "yes" "yes" NA
```

Here is the code I am attempting to us:

```
sapply(df,function(x)
which(x== if(df>2) 
{
list(df[,]) 
}
))
```

The output I want is (as above) a vector with the following:

```
name, all fields that contain NA (i.e. 1_1, 1_2 etc.)
name, all fields that contain NA (i.e. 1_1, 1_2 etc.)
etc.
```

The R output I get is:

```
$John integer(0)

$Peter integer(0)

$Steve integer(0)

$yes integer(0)

$yes integer(0)

$yes integer(0)

$yes integer(0)

$yes integer(0)

$ integer(0)

$ integer(0)

$yes integer(0)

$yes integer(0)

$ integer(0)

$ integer(0)

$yes integer(0)

$ integer(0)

$ integer(0)

$ integer(0)
```

Thus, does not work at all. Any pointers?

Thanks again.

Levi

Comment: your data doesn't work for me, please check my edits to see if this is what it looks like, if not you can change it to the correct code. I'm not sure what the `gsub` is supposed to be doing, can you clarify your question further

Comment: The `gsub` just adds `NA` into all the blank spaces. I did this because my original data set does not have `NA` in all of the blank spaces. I used your code and then the `gsub` and I get back the following:   ` names   X1_1  X1_2  X1_3  X1_4  X1_5
[1,] "John"  "yes" "yes" NA    NA    NA  
[2,] "Peter" "yes" "yes" "yes" NA    NA  
[3,] "Steve" "yes" NA    "yes" "yes" NA`  I am trying to get an output that should contain: name, spaces that contain NAs. See my edits above.

Comment: Your speech is not consistent through the comments and the post above. Do you want an output that gives "True" for each name that contains an NA? Or NA and a blank? What format should the output be in? Could you please post an exact example output that you would expect if you found the solution? edit: Thank you!

Comment: @David I am looking for an output that contains the name (i.e. the first row name and the column names contain NA's (i.e. 1_1, 2_1 etc).

Answer (score 1):

This is a `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
df<-data.frame(list(names = c("John", "Peter", "Steve"),
                '1_1' = c("yes", "yes","yes"),
                '1_2' = c("yes", "yes", ""),
                '1_3' = c("", "yes", "yes"),
                '1_4' = c("", "","yes"),
                '1_5' = c(NA, NA, NA)), 
           row.names = NULL)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
# Instead of using gsub, have a function that sets values True
# if the cell value != 'yes' or is NA.
dt.i <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x != 'yes' | is.na(x)), by=names]
# See dt.i:
#    names  X1_1  X1_2  X1_3  X1_4 X1_5
# 1:  John FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
# 2: Peter FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
# 3: Steve FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
dt.i[, list(list(names(.SD)[which(.SD == T)])), by=names]
```

Yields

```
   names             V1
1:  John X1_3,X1_4,X1_5
2: Peter      X1_4,X1_5
3: Steve      X1_2,X1_5
```

If you store this structure as

`dt.final <- dt.i[, list(list(names(.SD)[which(.SD == T)])), by=names]`

You can access the information by *e.g.*

```
dt.final[names == 'John']
#    names             V1
# 1:  John X1_3,X1_4,X1_5
dt.final[names == 'John']$V1
# [[1]]
# [1] "X1_3" "X1_4" "X1_5"
```

Comment: Thanks so much @David.